# Twenty Fifteen Premium Theme

Tags: themes, premium

I am wondering if GPL License allow us to make premium theme from Twenty Fifteen Wordpress. Can We customize such themes and sell? Please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: There are a couple of posts that already handles this section. Please use the site search

Comment: But, my question is not just about twenty fifteen. I tried to search but didnot find any post related with it.

Comment: Licensing is a legal issue and can't be answered here, frankly. There are people high up in WordPress development who disagree on all of the implication, in fact.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  this involves professional legal advice which cannot be handled here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at what the GPL License entails. This Wikipedia article does a pretty good job of explaining:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License

"Any licensee who adheres to the terms and conditions is given permission to modify the work, as well as to copy and redistribute the work or any derivative version. The licensee is allowed to charge a fee for this service, or do this free of charge."

Hope that helps